# PHP Parse syntax error in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have this pseudo-code that I've been trying to create the correct PHP syntax for and
I am getting absolutely nowhere. I continue to get a Parse error on the function group_job_items.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 17

What's wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function group_job_items ()
{
    $jobs_by_category = array();
    foreach ($category_name as $category_id => $name)
    {
        foreach ($job_item as $item)
        {
            // skip job items that do not match the current category
            if ($item["category_id"] != $category_id) continue;

            if (!isset ($jobs_by_category[$name])
            {
                // create a list of jobs for the current category
                $jobs_by_category[$name] = array();
            }

            // add the current job item to the current category
            $jobs_by_category[$name][] = $item
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Count the opening and closing parentheses; you’re missing a closing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function group_job_items ()
{
    $jobs_by_category = array();
    foreach ($category_name as $category_id => $name)
    {
        foreach ($job_item as $item)
        {
            // skip job items that do not match the current category
            if ($item["category_id"] != $category_id) continue;

            if (!isset ($jobs_by_category[$name]))
            {
                // create a list of jobs for the current category
                $jobs_by_category[$name] = array();
            }

            // add the current job item to the current category
            $jobs_by_category[$name][] = $item;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change...

```
if (!isset ($jobs_by_category[$name])
            {
                // create a list of jobs for the current category
                $jobs_by_category[$name] = array();
            }
```

to

```
if (!isset ($jobs_by_category[$name]))
            {
                // create a list of jobs for the current category
                $jobs_by_category[$name] = array();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There a few syntax errors in the code submitted.

A closing parenthesis/bracket is missing at the end of this line:

```
if (!isset ($jobs_by_category[$name])
```

A semi-colon is missing at the end of this line:

```
$jobs_by_category[$name][] = $item
```

Making these corrections should resolve the PHP parser errors.